Formatting of cites using mkdocs
So I'm using mkdocs-bibtex plugin for my bibliography.
What I don't like is that they are rendered as footnotes.
Is it possible to change that to, e.g. "as described in [1]" contrary to "as described in^1"?
Not sure if it helps, but this is my YML:
plugins:
  - glightbox
  - search 
  - macros
  - bibtex:
      bib_file: "references.bib"
      csl_file: "physical-review-letters.csl"
      cite_inline: true

